# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException' after MOC.rollback()

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, nsmanagedobject, reloaddata

I get an error when i make a self.tableView.reloadData() after the cancel of appending a new row in UITableView with Swift.

[image]

First i make managedObjectContext.rollback() and then a self.tableView.reloadData() to refresh the tableView:

```
 func cancel() {
    if self.managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        self.managedObjectContext.rollback()        
        self.tableView.reloadData()
   }
}
```

This causes the error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
>   *

This error make sense, cause

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)
```

returns **7**, but i think after the rollback the result should be **6** as shown in the screenshot above!

I´m struggling with this for about hours and can´t find a solution....

Comment: Your error message says the problem is an index of 1, not of 6 or 7.

Comment: @Tom Harrington: you´re right, of course, another reason, why i don´t understand that...

Comment: What I was getting at was, you might not be looking at the right place in the code.

Comment: @Tom Harrington: i **fear** that i´m not looking at the right place but i don´t know, where this may be. I tried a lot, i.e. delegates. But can´t find something. :-(

Comment: If you add an exception breakpoint and run the app, you should be able to find the stack trace when the error happens.

Comment: @Tom Harrington:  thanks, good idea! I did this too rarely til know :-(

Comment: @Tom Harrington: thanks a lot, you where absolute right! I´ve found it immediately. :-) The reason was silly: self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems

Comment: @Tom Harrington: you saved my night :-)